# Passband Attenuation

Tags: filters

I just started out in signal processing I am trying to make a low pass filter with a 0 - 10000Hz Passband and has a maximum attenuation of 3db. Is the passband attenuation the same as the passband ripple? If so why is it that even though I am using a Bessel filter I still have a passband ripple of -3db?    [image: Frequency Response][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passband attenuation refers to the maximum signal loss within the passband of the filter which should ideally be zero; i.e., pass band shall not attenuate the signal it passes; it's a unit gain region.

The term **ripple** is about of alternating gain through the passband for certain filter types yet it's still used even if the passband is not alternating such as a Butterworth filter. In that case the frequency at which the gain reduces to -3dB is the cutoff frequency for a lowpass filter. Or similarly high and low cutoff frequencies for a bandpass filter.